# Poisson distribution of false alarms

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have this problem:

The daily amount $X$ of burglar alarms has the Poisson distribution with parametr $\lambda>0$: $$P[X=k]=\dfrac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}, k=0,1,...$$

It is known that $15\%$ of the alarms are a false ones. What is the distribution and the expected value of the daily amount $Y$ of false alarms?

My only idea was to put $Y=0,15X$ but that is probably a stupidity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use that equality because, by definition, $X$ and $Y$ have to be integer-valued. Instead of that, express the *expectation* of $X$ (not necessarily an integer) in terms of $\lambda$ and notice that the expectation of $Y$ must be $15\%$ of that - yielding another Poisson distribution (with a different parameter).

Comment: EX is equal to $\lambda$, so then you would write $$P[Y=k]=\frac{(0,15\lambda)^k}{k!}e^{-0,15\lambda}$$?

Comment: That seems correct, yes.